# One google-service.json file for multiple android projects, push notifications

Tags: firebase, push-notification, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have multiple different android projects within 1 solution, I need to have 1 google-service.json file for those projects for sending remote push notifications. Is it possible?(Here all android projects have different package names)

Comment: If all the Android apps are using the same Firebase project, if you download the google-services json file, I believe it should contain all the details needed of the said apps.

Comment: If all the Android apps are using the same Firebase project. This statement seems incorrect, why because every android app different package name & firebase project taking 1 package name for 1 project(I think so).

Comment: You can add multiple Android Projects to a single Firebase Project. I've been using the Firebase console and developing Android apps for quite sometime. I'm positive this is correct. I suggest you explore the Firebase Console more.

Comment: Yeah in single firebase project we can add multiple android project with different package names. Those project have 1 .json file for each.

Comment: Did you even look inside the content of the json file? Regardless of which app you download it for, the contents are the same, all android projects included in one file.

Comment: I have tried checking .json file for 2 different projects those are totally different.